# jqgrid - calendar icon not showing up in inline editing mode

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jqgrid

The calendar icon is not showing up when in inline editing mode. I'm using *jquery.ui.datepicker.js*

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Jquery Grid</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.multiselect.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.corner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
        <script src="plugins/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="userinfo">
                <table id="myjqgrid"></table>
                <div id="Pager"></div>                  
                <script src="js/myjqgrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                   
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "colModel": [
        {
            "name": "ID",
            "label": "ID",
            "width": 60,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.0.value",
            "sortable": true      
        },
        {
            "name": "FirstName",
            "label": "FirstName",
            "width": 100,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.1.value",
            "sortable": false       
        },
        {
            "name": "LastName",
            "label": "LastName",
            "width": 100,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.2.value",
            "sortable": false       
        },
        {
            "name": "Date",
            "label": "Date",
            "width": 100,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.3.value",
            "sortable": false       
        }
    ],
    "colNames": [
        "ID",
        "FirstName",
        "LastName",
        "Date"
    ],
    "mypage": {
        "outerwrapper": {
            "page":"1",
            "total":"1",
            "records":"20",
            "innerwrapper": {
                "rows":[
                    {
                        "id":"1",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"12345",
                                "label": "ID",
                                "editable": false                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"David",
                                "label": "FirstName",
                                "editable": false    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Smith",
                                "label": "LastName",
                                "editable": false                         
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"01/02/2012",
                                "label": "Date",
                                "editable": true,
                                "editformat": "text"                         
                            }                                                                                        
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"2",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"37546",
                                "label": "ID",
                                "editable": false                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Willy",
                                "label": "FirstName",
                                "editable": false    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Peacock",
                                "label": "LastName",
                                "editable": false                         
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"01/02/2012",
                                "label": "Date",
                                "editable": true,
                                "editformat": "text"                         
                            }                                                                                        
                        ]       
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**JQGrid Definition**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var serverData = [];
    var showCalImg = function(id){
        $("#" + id + "_date").datepicker({
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: 'mmddyy',
            buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif'
        });
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myjqgrid.json",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            var columnData = response.mypage.outerwrapper,
                columnNames = response.colNames,
                columnModel = response.colModel;

            $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                datastr: columnData,                
                colNames: columnNames,
                colModel: columnModel,
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "innerwrapper.rows",              
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                gridview: true,
                pager: "#Pager",
                rowNum: 21,
                rowList: [21],
                viewrecords: true,              
                recordpos: 'left',
                multiboxonly: true,
                multiselect: true,
                sortname: 'ID',
                sortorder: "desc",  
                sorttype: "text",   
                sortable: true,
                caption: "<h2>MY JQGRID</h2>",
                width: "1406",      
                height: "100%",
                scrolloffset: 0,    
                loadonce: true,     
                cache: true,
                onSelectRow: function(id) {
                    $("table#myjqgrid").editRow(id, true, showCalImg);
                },
                loadComplete: function(){
                    var rowCounter, cellCounter, cellProperty, itemRows;
                    for (rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < response.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows.length; rowCounter++) {
                        itemRows = response.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows[rowCounter];
                        serverData[itemRows.recordnbr] = itemRows.cells;                        
                        var cellCount = response.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows[rowCounter].cells.length;
                        for (cellCounter = 0; cellCounter < cellCount; cellCounter += 1) {
                            cellProperty = response.mypage.outerwrapper.innerwrapper.rows[rowCounter].cells[cellCounter];
                            var isEditable = cellProperty.editable;
                            var cellEditFormat = cellProperty.editformat;
                            if (isEditable === false) {
                                $("#myjqgrid").setColProp(cellProperty.label, {
                                    editable: false
                                });
                            }else{
                                if (isEditable === true) {
                                    $("#myjqgrid").setColProp(cellProperty.label, {
                                        editable: true,
                                        edittype: cellProperty.editformat,
                                        editoptions: {
                                            size: cellProperty.size,
                                            maxlength: cellProperty.maxlength
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#Pager', {add:false, edit:false, del:false, position: 'right'});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem in your code that the JSON data don't includes `size` and `maxlength` properties. If one don't use `size` property of the `editoptions` the `width: 98%` will be set by inline editing on the `<input>` and one will have no place to display the button.

The next problem is that you use `"name": "Date"` for the Date column, but uses `$("#" + id + "_date")` instead of `$("#" + id + "_Date")` in your code. So the datepicker will be not initialized.

Additional problem: if you include `jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js` the code of the `datepicker` will be already included and you don't need to include `jquery.ui.datepicker.js` additionally.

The last problem is that `datepicker` with `showOn: 'button'` works only if you start `datepicker` in the separate thread with respect of `setTimeout` JavaScript function.

After fixing the described above problem the code will work (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11-9_.htm)), but the position of the icon will be not so nice:

[image]

To fix the position of the `<img>` you can use the following code directly after the `datepicker` initialization:

```js
$("#" + id + ' img.ui-datepicker-trigger').css({
    position: "relative",
    top: "4px"
});
```

As the result you will have the following results (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11-9.htm))

[image]

I personally would prefer don't use any images in the buttons and use jQuery UI Buttons instead. I created [one more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DatepickerWithShowOnButton.htm) which shows the way which looks me better.

The column with the date I would defines as

```js
{ name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 110, template: dateTemplate }
```

using `template`. The `dateTemplate` I would define as

```js
var dateTemplate = {align: 'center', sorttype: 'date', editable: true,
        formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-M-Y' }, datefmt: 'd-M-Y',
        editoptions: { dataInit: initDateWithButton, size: 11 },
        searchoptions: {
            sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'],
            dataInit: initDateWithButton,
            size: 11,          // for the advanced searching dialog
            attr: {size: 11}   // for the searching toolbar
        }};
```

(the format of the date you can choose any which corresponds your requirements). The function `initDateWithButton` can be defined as

```js
var initDateWithButton = function (elem) {
        if (/^\d+%$/.test(elem.style.width)) {
            // remove % from the searching toolbar
            elem.style.width = '';
        }
        // to be able to use 'showOn' option of datepicker in advance searching dialog
        // or in the editing we have to use setTimeout
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(elem).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                showOn: 'button',
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                showWeek: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                    inst.input.focus();
                }
            });
            $(elem).next('button.ui-datepicker-trigger').button({
                text: false,
                icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-calculator'}
            }).find('span.ui-button-text').css('padding', '0.1em');
        }, 100);
    };
```

As the result you would have the datepicker which looks like on the picture

[image]

Comment: would you know how to solve this? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107258/jqgrid-how-to-add-parameters-to-extraparam-of-saverow-in-inline-editing-mode

Comment: @Andrus: I am not sure that I understand what you mean, but why not just increase the `width` property of the `'invdate'` column from `width: 110` to some higher value?

Comment: @Oleg: Increasing width add extra free space to right. I'm looking for a way to decrease date field width to remove unused empty space. I posted this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619480/how-to-decrease-jqgrid-date-column-width

Comment: @Andrus: I posted you the answer.