# Jquery datepicker button tabindex

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm using the Jquery date/datetimepicker add-on(s), as well as JQgrid.
I'd like the onShow for the date/datetimepicker to be 'button', but when tabbing through the modal, the date/datetime button mustn't get focus.

Iv'e written a function to create the datepicker for me.

```
function CreateDatePicker(elem, ShowOn) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(elem).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
            autoSize: false,
            showOn: ShowOn,
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            showWeek: true,
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                $(this).focus();
            }
        });
    }, 100);

    $(elem).mask("9999/99/99", { placeholder: "_" });
}
```

**I call it like this.**

```
initDateEdit = function (elem) {
        CreateDatePicker(elem, 'button');
};
```

**JQgrid code**

```
{ name: 'Date', index: 'Date', editable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 2 }, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'Y/m/d' }, datefmt: 'Y/m/d', editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit }, searchoptions: { dataInit: initDateSearch } },
```

I saw that the datepicker renders like this

```
<input type="text" id="Date" name="Date" role="textbox" class="FormElement ui-widget-content ui-corner-all hasDatepicker">
<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger">...</button>
```

So my initial idea was to latch on to the button class and use Jquery to jump to the next (input) element on the page, regardless of what it is.

I've tried a couple of things, all yielding either incorrect/no results at all...

**My last failed attempt...**

```
    $(document).delegate('.ui-datepicker-trigger', 'focus', function (event) {
        $(this).next().focus();
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated.. a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most direct way to solve the problem seems me to set [tabindex](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) to "-1":

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(elem).datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        ...
    }).next('button.ui-datepicker-trigger')
      .attr("tabIndex", "-1");
```

Try to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> in the searching toolbar of [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DatepickerWithShowOnButton1_small3.htm) and compare the results with [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DatepickerWithShowOnButton1_small2_.htm) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9620311/315935).

Comment: aha! i tried the the tabindex -1 thing earlier, but had nooo idea how to append it to the button via jquery. thanks for the answer again.

Comment: that link is broken. also, setting tabindex doesnt seem to work on samsung galaxy s4.

Answer (score 1):

So my initial idea was to latch on to the button class and use jQuery to jump to the next input element on the page, regardless of what it is.

Comment: I wont lie, your wisdom confuses me.. :/